# What is the opposite of "pre-payment"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

If I want to say that someone can pay for something after receiving a good, service or job done (as opposed to a pre-payment) with a specific amount of money, can I say

> You can use this feature for **the post-fee of** $20

Or the only correct option is *"for the post-payment fee of $20"* ?

The prefix *"post"* here only refers to a payment opposed to a pre-payment and has nothing to do with the post mailing service.

Comment: Neither "post-fee"nor "post-payment fee" are in common use in standard English.  "post-fee" **could** mean a fee for mailing something, but I don't think that is the meaning here either. Please explain more clearly just what sort of fee or charge you have in mind here. Is this a fee charged after an initial purchase?

Comment: By a "post-payment" do you mean an additional fee charged after an initial payment? or a fee charged after a purchase? Or a purchase made on credit, with payment later?  I am afraid I do not find this question clear yet.

Comment: I think it's assumed that you pay for something when you receive it unless _pre-payment_ is specified. I would say _payment of $20 on receipt_.

Comment: If it's a service rather than a physical item, you can call the payment a fee.

Comment: Why not use the term invoice?

Comment: There are various terms like **payment in arrears**, **purchase on account**, **buying on credit**, etc, which mean payment is made after receipt of the goods. This depends on whether it's consumer or business-to-business and the exact payment schedule (e.g. is an invoice sent with the goods and prompt payment expected, or are goods sold with the understanding that you don't have to pay until a certain time has elapsed). There's also e.g. **cash on delivery/payment on delivery**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the assumption is that you pay for goods or services when you receive them, unless *pre-payment* is specified. For a physical item, you could say *payment of $20 on receipt* (when it arrives). For a service, you can call it a *fee.* If you are paying someone to do a job for you, you could say something like *on completion of work.*

In response to your later question - if you regularly buy items, for instance from a mail-order company, you may have an account with them - they keep a record of what you owe and you can add money to it at any time rather than paying for each purchase separately. This can be called *payment on account.*

(Disclaimer - I'm not a financial expert, but this is how I understand the terms.)

Answer (score 2):

I would have used to term **invoice**, saying something like:

> You can use this feature for a **fee** of $20 **to be paid by invoice**.
> or
> You can use this feature for a **fee** of $20, **paid by invoice**.

Comment: Can it be also something like _"for the invoice payment of $..."_ or _"for the invoice fee of $..."_ ?

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of "pre-payment" is "post-payment". So, the correct phrase to use in your sentence would be "post-payment fee of $20".

While "post-fee" might convey the intended meaning of payment after receiving the good or service, it is not a commonly used term in this context, and may cause confusion or be misleading. "Post-fee" could also potentially be interpreted as referring to a fee for some kind of post or mailing service. Therefore, it would be clearer and more appropriate to use the more common term "post-payment" in this context.

Comment: Yes, I was heard or read about _"post-payment"_ as the opposite of _"pre-payment"_ many years ago. But now here at SE I'm wondering that noone (except you now) mentioned such an option and someone even became associated it with the post mailing service. Could you specify some authoritative sources or at least simply web pages where _"post-payment"_ is mentioned?

Comment: Based on the context you gave, I would suggest using "post-payment", since audiences could understand if you mentioned "pre-payment" before.
However, I just asked one of my friends who's studying business, he said  __"balance"__ or __"due"__ would be more common because it means __owned to someone either as a debt or because they **have a right to it**__. [Longman Dic: Due](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/due)

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean _"for the due payment of $..."_? You may add it to your answer

Answer (score 0):

"Post-fee" and "post-payment fee" are rarely used by native English speakers. The usual word is **postage** hence

> You can use this feature to pay the $20 postage.
> or
> You can use this feature to pay $20 for [the] postage.

"the" is optional in the second version.

Comment: "postage" refers to a payment for mailing something. I don't think that is what the OP is referring to here.

Comment: @DavidSiegel You could well be right, I didn't think of it that way. In which case my answer is completely wrong! A post-payment could then be something like **invoiced / 
 billed amount** You perform a service or supply goodes and include an invoice (or bill) which the client then pays afterwards.

Comment: Note the recent edits to the question by he OP.